# Trouble with attribute name as a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

in my project, jQuery doesn't select the "clicked" element.

Here is my current code:

```
$(function() {
    $('[data-sample_attribute]').click(function() {
        alert("sample text");
    });
});
```

I have no idea how to fix it.

Here is the element I am trying to select:

```
<div class="test" data-sample_attribute="test"></div>
```

Comment: Explain also what you mean with "select" here. What are you expecting ?

Comment: Seems to work fine from here: http://jsfiddle.net/7XDNv/ Maybe you're adding the `div` to the DOM at a later point (through AJAX or another event perhaps?)

Comment: It works for me too :) http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/fWC95/

Comment: Maybe it is, because I use it in an external file. Although I used the <script> tag properly, it only works, when I add the java script code after wards with the web kit js console.

Comment: @T.Lange If you expect help with your problem you _need_ to explain your specific scenario. Would you mind editing the correct details of the more specific problem into the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your **exact** code works.](http://jsfiddle.net/ysGx8/)

As you're using it in an external file (as stated in comments), it seems that your element **doesn't exist on document ready**, so you need to add a delegated event to it (such as `on`).

Try this:

```
$('body').on("click", "[data-sample_attribute]", function() {
    alert("sample text");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its a dynamic element, added after DOM is ready. In this case, use delegation:

```
    $(document).on('click','[data-sample_attribute]',function() {
        alert("sample text");
    });
```